# How to get column Header values in column as a result ?? Sql Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i am beginner and trying to get column header values in column such that it there values not equal to '0.0' or '0'

my query is,

```
select M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9,M10 from [dbo].[Target]
```

Result of query is,

```
M1   M2   M3   M4   M5   M6   M7   M8   M9   M10
0    5.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  2.0  3.0  9.0  0    0.0
```

I am trying to get result in this format,

```
M2  5.0
M4  1.0
M6  2.0
M7  3.0
M8  9.0
```

column having "0" and "0.0" do not list in query result

Hopes for your suggestion thanks in Advance.

Comment: man check out @M.Ali answer to my question a couple days ago. i had [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911613/transpose-2-columns-multiple-rows-to-1-rows-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT ColName,Value
FROM dbo.Target t
UNPIVOT (Value for ColName in (M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9,M10)) u
WHERE Value != 0
```

See [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Result:

```
ColName               Value
--------------------- ----------------------
M2                    5
M4                    1
M6                    2
M7                    3
M8                    9
```

Comment: it work a little bit but it is showing column again and again having not zero value ?